# PHP session variables and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session, variables

So, I've got a bit of an issue handling PHP session variables. I've got a jQuery function to post the variable to a PHP file (working, see code here):

```
   $('#practiceid').blur(function() {
    var practiceid = $(this).val();
    $.post("delicious.php", {"pid": practiceid});
   });
```

Thanks to Firebug I can see that delicious.php receives the variable. Now, the code in that PHP file is:

```
$_SESSION['uploaddir'] = $_POST['pid'];
```

The issue now is that when I try to use the session variable in other PHP files it just seems not to exist. I've declared the `session_start();` in the index.php file.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much.

Comment: `session_start()` doesn't just _initiate_ a session. It creates access to the session on any page that uses it, and must be called on _every_ script that reads or writes `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you make sure session_start() is called on *every* page that needs to use the $_SESSION member?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work. Should the session be _started_ that many times anyway?

Comment: @user1342734: The session isn't "started" by calling `session_start()` in the sense that you're thinking.  The session is active regardless.  What `session_start()` does is allow the rest of the script to access the session.  So, yes, it should be called at the start of every request if you're relying on session state throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` needs to be written on every page where you are using session values.

Also, don't directly assign values to SESSION variable. USe this :-

```
if(isset($SESSION['uploaddir'])){
 unset($_SESSION['uploaddir']); 
} 
$_SESSION['uploaddir'] = $_POST['pid'];
```

The assignment you used may lead to warnings